# Servlet value is not showing in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I've tested a simple test on servlet. I want to show the value I made in servlet to JSP but it seems its not appearing. Here's my code.

**Test.java(servlet):**

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String message = "hello";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet-test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**servlet-test.jsp(page):**

```
<p>Message: ${message}</p>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fluxion.mrcos.actions.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then when I'm about to view it in the page the value is not appearing. Someday can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What is the URL you are hitting?

Comment: The jsp itself. Like www.example.com/context/servlet-test.jsp

Comment: You seem to need a better tutorial as you seem to be not understanding at exactly all what all that code is doing under the covers. Put your mouse on top of `[servlets]` tag below the question until a black box appears and then click therein *info* link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `/servlet-test.jsp` directly which would mean that the servlet would never get called!

You should be hitting the URL of the servlet, `/Test` instead of directly going to the JSP, '/servlet-test.jsp`.

This is the reason a common practice is to hide the JSPs from being accessed directly by placing them under a directory under the `WEB-INF` directory.

Then your request dispatcher line would change to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/servlet-test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

So the URL you hit should be

```
www.example.com/context/Test
```

Comment: That is what I have done. My jsp file is under WEB-INF and also I went to address `www.example.com/context/Test` and it says `There is no Action mapped for namespace`

Comment: Does your servlet have a package declaration that matches the one you've defined in `web.xml`? Also, can you put a print statement in the `doGet` and see if the servlet is getting invoked?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure about the declaration in web.xml. I'm not done yet in print statemtn in doGet.

Comment: Also, make sure you have `/WEB-INF` in `request.getRequestDispatcher` line.

Comment: I've added /WEB-INF now, still no value appearing.

Comment: What url should I use? `www.example.com/context/Test?` or `www.example.com/context/servlet-test.jsp? since I have dispatched it to the page`

Comment: You should use `/Test`. Can you show me the exact line you have in request dispatcher call?

Comment: `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/servlet-test.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Answer (score -1):

Solved it! Just add extension to **url-pattern**

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Test.do</url-pattern>
```

and also I remove the WEB-INF in **request.getRequestDispatcher**(this is the part I don't understand but it works.)

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet-test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: The extension in URL has totally no influence on the concrete problem. The first part of your "answer" makes therefore no utter sense. The `/WEB-INF` should be removed if you didn't actually put the JSP in `/WEB-INF` (which in turn causes that everyone else in the world can see it without invoking the servlet first --which in turn causes that JSP can be seen without any message). Also not the recommended approach.

Comment: I'm very sure that its under /WEB-INF, because all of my jsp files are in  there that's why I said "I dont understand why is that happening", don't be so harsh on delivering words.

Comment: I second what @BalusC has said. I think your directory structure is wrong. Whatever you do, you must make sure that the path you use for request dispatcher matches the directory structure exactly. Having `.do` is not really the solution.